# How does $\mathcal{L}^1$-convergence of a series of $\mathcal{L}^1$ random variables imply that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}[|X_n|] < \infty$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a series of random variables with $\forall i: X_i \in \mathcal{L}^1(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$ and $X_n \rightarrow^{\mathcal{L}^1}X$. How do I show then, that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}[|X_n|] < \infty$?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: write 
$$\sup_i\mathbb E|X_i|\leqslant \max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant N}\mathbb E|X_i|+\sup_{j\geqslant N}\mathbb E|X_j-X|+\mathbb E|X|.$$
If $N$ is chosen such that $\sup_{j\geqslant N}\mathbb E|X_j-X|\lt 1$, we get 
$$\sup_i\mathbb E|X_i|\leqslant \max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant N}\mathbb E|X_i|+1+\mathbb E|X|.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but we don't know, whether $\mathbb{E}[|X|]$ or even $\mathbb{E}[X]$ converges, do we?

Comment: $\mathbb E|X|$ is finite by Fatou's lemma.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm asking total nonsense questions, but how does that follow? I get to the point $\mathbb{E}[|X|] = \mathbb{E}[|\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n|] = \mathbb{E}[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |X_n|] \leq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathbb{E}[|X_n|]$. But since the right side can be infinite, this does not lead me anywhere...

Comment: But now I found a proof for it being finite by Jensen inequality... Thanks for your help.